# geom_text() & color gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am looking to set a color gradient from green for low and red for high on the geom_text function. My code is as follows:

```
mydata <-  data.frame(R_Test_Data)

datatime <- mydata$TIMESTAMP
wind_speed <- mydata$WS_ms_Avg
wind_direction <-mydata$WS_ms_WVc

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = datatime, y = wind_speed))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(angle=-wind_direction + 270), label="→", 
            colour = wind_speed, size = 7 ) +
 scale_colour_gradient(low="green", high="red")
```

[image: This is my result]

I am looking for something kind of like this:

[image: What I am looking for]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is best practice to provide a reproducible example. In your case, `R_Test_Data` and the required library calls are missing.

Comment: You may want `geom_spoke` instead of `geom_text` for adding angled arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map colour to to a numeric variable - e.g. this maps color to `y` by specifying `color=y` within `aes`:

```
set.seed(1);df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, angle = runif(10,90,180))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(angle=angle, color=y), label="-", size = 12) + 
  scale_colour_distiller(palette="RdYlGn")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I will also be better at my post formatting in the future.